# Change link based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the link based on radio selection. I am actually able to make it work but not able to right-click and open the link in a new tab. Here is my code

```
<label class="container">One
  <input type="radio" id="optionone" checked="checked" name="radio">
</label>

<label class="container">Two
  <input type="radio" id="optiontwo" name="radio">
</label>

<label class="container">Three
  <input type="radio" id="optionthree" name="radio">
</label>

<div>
  <a href="" onclick='myFunction()' id="linkid">Click Here</a>
</div>
```

Js code to change the link

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {

        if(document.getElementById('optionone').checked) {
            document.getElementById('linkid').href = "#link1";
        }

      if(document.getElementById('optiontwo').checked) {
            document.getElementById('linkid').href = "#link2";
        }

      if(document.getElementById('optionthree').checked) {
            document.getElementById('linkid').href = "#link3";
        }
    }
</script>
```

As I said above it works but not if the user wants to open a link in a new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `onclick` to the radio buttons instead, changing the `href` of the link before the link is clicked or right-clicked.

Comment: Thank you for your help, So I added `onclick="myFunction()"` to the radio buttons which kinda works and I am not sure if that's what you meant but it doesn't work with the already checked option.

Comment: I added a default link for the first option and now it seems working. `<a href="first-link.php" onclick='myFunction()' id="linkid">Click Here</a>`